# How to bind strongSwan to specific IP on VPS with multiple IPs?

Tags: ip, strongswan

I would like client traffic to show publicly as originating from that specific IP (which could be a secondary IP assigned to the same network interface as primary).

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 167.99.179.140/24
    gateway 167.99.179.1
iface eth0 inet static
    address 167.99.179.141/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I had to replace `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` by `-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 167.99.179.141` in `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`.